# Probability of case solved

Tags: probability

**Two sleuths A and B are given a case to solve. The chance that A solves the case is 1/5 and that B solves it is 1/6. Find the probability that
   the case is solved**

This is the question

I thought its 1/5 + 1/6...but the answer given is 1/5*1/6

1/30 is lesser than 1/5 and 1/6.. how is the probability of case getting solved lesser than their individual case solving probability??

Comment: Both answers are wrong ... unless there is something that guarantees that A and B cannot _both_ solve the case. (I don't think there's a clear _right_ answer, though, unless we assume that A solving the case is _independent_ of B solving the case, which sounds like a very unrealistic assumption).

Comment: ${1\over 30}={1\over 5}-{1\over 6}$ so $1\over 30$ is also the minimum amount of cases that A will solve that B wont.

Comment: shouldnt that be 1/5*(5/6) ...P(A success)*P(B fail) ??

Comment: |*^|*^|*^|*^|*| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |  the spaces are empty when neither solve the ^ are when B solves, * are when A solves there are 30 separate areas ( if I copied correctly) only one has * in it without ^ in it as well.

Comment: it of course as pointed out already depends on if overlap is allowed etc.

Comment: Oh got it!! Thanks

Comment: it could also just be a typo of 11/30 = 1/5+1/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ the events such as

$A:$ sleuth A solves tha case

$B:$ sleuth B solves the case

The probability you are looking for is

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{30}=\frac{1}{3}$